# Python complex problem of for loop & if statements

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need your help as I am new to programming hence my knowledge is limited to things I learned out of my own interest.
Basically I have an excel file that contains the following data:

[image]

I want to perform the following logical steps on this.

1. Cell C1 will be noted as "X", i.e. `X=ws.['C1']`. Y will be = X-5
   & then `print('X=' + str(X))`
2. check if Cell C2 is less than or equal to Y;
   i. If yes, then `Y=Cell ['C2']` & then `print('Y=' +str(Y))`
        & now X will be the next cell, i.e. X=ws.['C3']. Y will be = new X-5. 
        & then `print('X=' + str(X))`. 
        Again check for the same condition(loop) mentioned in point 2.

   ii. If No, i.e. C2>Y, then Y=Cell[C2]-5. 
   Again check for the condition mentioned in point 2.

I am using the following code which, I know is wrong.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime
wb = load_workbook('D:/Python/data.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
X=float(ws["C2"].value)
print('X=' +str(X))
Y=float(X - 5)

for row in range(2, ws.max_row + 1):
    cell=float(ws['C' +str(row)].value)
    if cell < Y:
        Y=cell
        print('Y='+str(Y))

    else:
        Y=cell-5
        X=float(ws['C' +str(row)+1].value)
        print('X=' +str(X))
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Please edit your question, (starting from the title!) look at this to get it right https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

work_book = load_workbook("62357026/source.xlsx")
work_sheet = work_book.active

buying_price = work_sheet["C2"].value  # Assuming all data are integer.
loss_threshold = buying_price - 5

print(f"Price = {buying_price}\nStarting Step 2:")

for index, row in enumerate(work_sheet.rows):
    a, b, c = row  # (<Cell 'Sheet1'.Ax>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.Bx>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.Cx>)

    print(f'\nrow {index}: {a.coordinate} {b.coordinate} {c.coordinate}')
    print(f'row {index}: {a.value} {b.value} {c.value}')

    price = row[2].value

    if price <= loss_threshold:
        loss_threshold = price
        print(f"threshold = {loss_threshold}")

    else:
        buying_price = price
        loss_threshold = buying_price - 5
        print(f"threshold = {loss_threshold}")
```

Results:

```
Price = 81
Starting Step 2:

row 0: A1 B1 C1
row 0: Mango Monday 31
threshold = 31

row 1: A2 B2 C2
row 1: Mango Tuesday 81
threshold = 76

row 2: A3 B3 C3
row 2: Mango Wednesday 89
threshold = 84

row 3: A4 B4 C4
row 3: Mango Thursday 84
threshold = 84

row 4: A5 B5 C5
row 4: Mango Friday 22
threshold = 22

row 5: A6 B6 C6
row 5: Mango Saturday 56
threshold = 51

row 6: A7 B7 C7
row 6: Mango Sunday 53
threshold = 48

row 7: A8 B8 C8
row 7: Mango Monday 94
threshold = 89

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Actually I wanted to determine X and Y as the value of cells of column C changes. So i think i can change the line of a, b, c = row. As i dont have numbers in a and b column. Thanks a ton for ur help. I will try this and update.

Comment: print change of X and Y as Column C moves 'down', right?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely.

Comment: This already iterate thru C1 to all the way down, actually. Lemme add more output.

Comment: I am facing an error of 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value' for  this code if c.value < y:

Comment: Ideally this should be my output.X=31
Y=84
X=22

Comment: a, b, c = (1,2,3) means a, b, c are assigned to 1, 2, 3 respectively, this is called 'tuple unpacking'. As 'row' is tuple, if you just do c = row, you get tuple.

Comment: Sorry, the error I am receiving is '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. For if c.value < y: this line

Comment: So basically this problem says; X represents the buying price, I will buy mangoes on Monday & on Tuesday if the price of mangos is less than 5 bucks; we should sell. & again buy it on Wednesday.  If the price is increased our loss threshold should also be increased which is represented by Y. So want to have all the X & Y i.e. buying price & selling price for all the cells of Col C by which I will be able to calculate the amount of profit/loss at the end of week/month.

Comment: Might been great it it was on question, I'll update post after changing my codes!

Comment: Sorry. could not explain it properly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: on row 2: A3 B3 C3
row 2: Mango Wednesday 89
X = 89
X will not be 89 it will be 81 only. since 89 is greater than the X the new Y will become 89-5=84. and when price goes below 84 we will sale.

Comment: Seems like I don't need to print x in that case?

Comment: Yes no need to print. X will be printed only when we have sold the earlier transaction. after we sold earlier transaction the next cell will become the X as will again buy on the price of next cell

Comment: Already changed code as requested, not printing X now. Thought You need X value for it just by looking at your codes.

Comment: Oh God. You are a genius. Thanks bro.

Comment: Did it work? Would be nice to accept this as answer if it help :)